# What are the consequences of a source terminator resistor that is too high of a resistance value?

Tags: impedance-matching, termination

What are the consequences of a source terminator resistor (placed in series with the output) that is too high of a resistance value?  Is it just a slower rise time at the input, or are there other consequences?  Do I make ringing/reflections WORSE at the input if the source terminator is too high?

I am wondering what can go wrong if I just put a source terminator resistor in series with an output that makes the series resistance greater than the characteristic impedance of a short transmission line? (When I say transmission line, I'm talking about wire of a few inches, paired with a ground wire of same length.)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about terminating a transmission line at first, but then talk about a GPIO pin.  I can't make out what you're asking, and even what you think "terminating" actually means.

Comment: I would not try to put 50uA through a transmission line.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - You're right, I will edit my question to get rid of the GPIO pin nonsense.  My question should be simple: What happens when the source terminator resistor is too large of a resistance value?

Comment: See figures 3 and 4 of [this application report](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sdya015).

Comment: Is the transmission line terminated in the characteristic impedance of the line? Most likely, if this is a digital signal only travelling a few inches, then it doesn't matter very much. You may not need the series termination at all.

Comment: It would take more than one reflection for the signal to reach (or exceed) the final level. One example, a 5V step is driven through a 100ohm resistor into a 50ohm line. The initial step would be 5V*50/150 = 1.66V. The 1.66V travels to the end of line terminated with high impedance receiver only. An 100% reflect gives 3.33V. If the receiver has a high threshold of 3.5V, then it can be trouble because the receiver may see this intermediate, invalid logic level until another round trip reflection.

Comment: @rioraxe That makes sense.  So it sounds like a consequence of a too-high series resistance is never rising above a minimum voltage for a high logic level, and I should be able to see this on a scope, too.

Comment: The signal would rise to the final level equals to the step driven, but it would just take more than one trip (one delay) down the line.

Comment: @rioraxe Ok, then that means the consequence is effectively a slower rise time at the input for logic high, correct?  With a matched series resistance, the rise time is the same at both the input and the output?

Comment: Yes, if the transmission line is short if would look like a slower rise time. With matching series resistance, at the output, the signal would be at half level that lasts for one round-trip delay. At the input, at the end of the line, the signal would rise to the full level immediately after the one-way delay.

Comment: @rioraxe Thanks.  If you create an answer with what we've talked about I'll probably mark the question as answered with your answer, assuming it's thorough enough.